# Null check and then Null ref Exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

```
Line1: if( m_Action != null )
Line2:     m_Action();    // Null ref Exception!!
```

- m_Action is Action class in C#.
- m_Action initialized in Constructor and then not changed.
- m_Action's method has polymorphism.
- This program is Multi-threaded.

I think m_Action indicate not null (super class's method)
but m_Action's method in the Null obj(child class). Why is this happening?

Comment: more details required.

Comment: Line 0: `Action m_action = () => { FooClass x = null; x.Bar(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null reference exception is being throw from the code in the Action, to find out where enable an exception breakpoint.

Debug->Exceptions and then check the Thrown column for Common Language Runtime Exceptions, the debugger will stop at the point the null reference exception is thrown.